# Ajax + PHP + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как корректно вывести данные получены от сервера.

Есть небольшой `MVC`-апликейшн.

Вот модель:

```
 public function getComments()
 {
     $db = Db::getInstance();
     $res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN users ON (comments.login_id = users.id) ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 10");
     $res->execute();
     $rez = $res->fetchAll();

     return $rez;
 }
```

Вот контроллер:

```
 public function action_getajax()
 {
     $this->model = new Model_Comments();
     $data[2] = $this->model->getComments();

     echo json_encode($data[2]);
 }
```

И вот пытаюсь на главной вывести все комментарии посредством `js`,`jquery+ajax`:

```html
    $(function() {

        var ids = [];

        setInterval(function() {
            myAjax();
           }, 3000
        );

        function myAjax() {
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/comments/getajax',
                 cahche: false,
                   type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             beforeSend: function() {
                  $('#myajax').html('Loading...');
             },
                success: function(data) {
                   $('#myajax').hide();
                    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                        if($.inArray(val.id, ids) == -1) {
                            ids.push(val.id);
                            $('#comments').prepend("<div class=\"panel panel-default\"><div class=\"panel-heading\"><b class=\"panel-title\"><b>" + val.login_id + " / " + val.date + "</div><div class=\"panel-body\">" + val.text + "</div></div>");
                        }
                    });
                },
                  error: function(msg) {
                  $('myajax').text(msg.responseText);
                },
            });
        };

    });
```

Но к сожалению оно некорректно выводит, только 3 последних.

Ответ приходит в таком виде (получается в виде обьектов `js`):

```
[{"id":"2","0":"6","login_id":"2","1":"2","text":"test AJAX comments!","2":"test AJAX comments!","date":"2017-05-26 20:39:41","3":"2017-06-05 11:41:23","4":"2","login":"test","5":"test","password":"1234","6":"1234","email":"tester@net.ua","7":"tester@net.ua","8":"2017-05-26 20:39:41"}, ... ]
```

Сначала пытался преобразовывать ответ через `JSON.parse()` и `JSON.stringify()`, но понял, что ответ уже отформатирован и остается только вывести. Выводить пробовал по-разному, но успеха нет.

Может кто подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего выводит последние из-за этого условия - `if($.inArray(val.id, ids) == -1)` выведите над ним `console.log` к примеру со значением `$.inArray(val.id, ids)` и проверьте все ли проходят проверку

Comment: Проходят проверку не все... Вот скрин https://prnt.sc/fg30as

Comment: Ну вот по этому и выводятся не все

Comment: И как же решить это, не подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем ковырял много доков и нашел одно решение для моего случая:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON("/comments/getajax", function(json) {

            var html = "";

            json.forEach(function(val) {
                var keys = Object.keys(val);
                html += "<div class = 'cat'>";
                keys.forEach(function(key) {
                    html += "<div class=\"panel panel-default\"><div class=\"panel-heading\"><b class=\"panel-title\"><b>" + val[key].login_id + "</b> / " + val[key].date + "</div><div class=\"panel-body\">" + val[key].text + "</div></div>";
                   // html += val[key].text + "<br>";
                });
                html += "</div><br>";
                $('#myajax').hide();
                $('#comments').html(html);
                console.log(html);
            });
        });
       }, 3000
    );
```

Остался ещё вопрос, в модели я делал запрос с left join'ом, что бы при выводе комментов выводился не id-автора а его ник, здесь же получается никак не получиться так сделать? Нужно уже отдавать Ajax'у готовый объект?